# Pandas: Aggregate same column twice -> _agg_2dim() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I can't figure out why i get the error message

"_agg_2dim() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

[image: The aggregation error in the .init of class]

I want to put empasis on the variable

```py
aggregation_dict = 
{'val0': NamedAgg(column='HW_Wirkstrom_Max', aggfunc='max'),
 'val1': NamedAgg(column='HW_Wirkstrom_Max', aggfunc='max')}
```

if instead, i choose two **different columns**, so

```py
aggregation_dict = 
{'val0': NamedAgg(column='HW_Wirkstrom_Max', aggfunc='max'),
 'val1': NamedAgg(column='HW_Wirkstrom_Schnitt', aggfunc='max')}
```

the code runs fine.

It also runs fine in case of the same column aggregated two times, if i run the snippet directly in a notebook:
[image]

This has been driving me crazy for the last few hours, i am not sure how to represent a working minimal example, as i can't reproduce the error in a notebook but only happens when calling an external class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two different columns with the same name and it's impossible. you can use agg function simply without having named agg:

```
df.groupby(something).agg({'val1':'max','val2':'max'})
```

Then rename the columns to what you want. or do what you do in your example and works.

Comment: My example is identical to the one where the error occurs (well obviously not quite) but the difference is what i want to find

Comment: The difference between the one that works and the one that does not work?

Comment: Yes. I find it strange that the change to aggregating the same column twice in contrast to two different columns causes this error. But the same change in the minimal example in the notebook is fine. Plus the error message is not really helpful for googling.
Also i can't host the package on git to really produce a minimal example, because of some blabla-policy.

Comment: You were right i think. I found the problem, before that i reindex the columns such that there is the same column twice. This leads to a problem when aggregating this same column twice. It pobably doesn't know which to choose. Thank you! Im stupid, but this error could have just said "Duplicate columns, ambiguous aggregation"